# How to create a Discord bot in C++ 98 with platform toolset version v120?

Tags: c++, discord, c++98

I'm working on a C++ 98 project with platform toolset version v120 on VS 2013. I'm trying to implement Discord bot API in my project. I've tried several unofficial Discord libraries for C++, like Sleepy-Discord, DPP, and Discord.CPP. But it seems like none of them are compatible with my project's C++/platform toolset version. Unfortunately, I cannot update my project as it's too big. I want to know if there's any solution for this.

**What I'm expecting:**

- A Discord lib for CPP compatible with my project's PTV v120.
- Or a way to downgrade one of the Discord libraries to make it compatible with my project.
- Or a way to interact with the Discord API through my project.
- Any other way.

Thank you.

Comment: This sort of thing is expected to happen if you choose not to upgrade your compiler and toolchain. Many modern libraries are just not going to be tested with decade-old tools. You're going to have to upgrade sooner or later, and doing so sooner will always be better for you.

Comment: C++98 is just too old. Discord did not even exist in 1998. It still did not exist in 2003, the next major C++ update. The chances of finding a Discord API library that supports such a historic C++ standard are not very good.

Comment: You’re highly unlikely to find anything c++98 compatible. It’s highly obsolete. You would be better off searching for a c library or moving to something more modern.

Comment: Pretty sure this type of question is also off topic btw.

Comment: and upgrading the platform toolset will be much better because you don't have to install vcredist.exe any more, all the new versions can use the same VC redistribute library

Comment: I tried updating my project and I got 10K+ syntax errors in the code. As I mentioned in the question, It's a big project it will take months to manually fix/update the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference), their API can be accessed entirely through web requests. You don't need any additional libraries, except if you want to use a prebuilt REST or WebSocket library for easier use, which - if available to you - i would highly recommend.